# Mapping a multiple dimensional JSON file to a Go struct

Tags: json, struct, go

Quick and easy question no doubt, but one that has me stumped.

**Sophie.conf**

```
{
    "host": {
        "domain": "localhost",
        "port": 5000
    }
}
```

**main.go**

```
...

type Config struct {
    domain string `json:"host.domain"`
    port   int    `json:"host.port"`
}

...

func loadConfig() {
    buffer, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE)
    fmt.Println(string(buffer))
    json.Unmarshal(buffer, &cfg)
}

...
```

That doesn't work though, if I print with

```
fmt.Printf("host: %s:%d\n", cfg.domain, cfg.port)
```

The output is:

```
host: :0
```

How would I do this properly? Thanks!

Comment: You can use a tool like [JSON-to-Go](http://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to convert JSON to a Go struct.

Comment: @Matt That's an useful tool, but I wanted to see how it's done properly, rather than having a tool do it for me.

Comment: That's good. But once you start working with larger JSON structures, it becomes unnecessarily tedious and repetitive to type out the struct definition one field at a time.

Comment: Absolutely, hence why I said that was an useful tool. Perhaps I should have also thanked you! My belated thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you should declare outer `Config` struct. Inside it you should define `Host` field, in my example it is anonymous struct, but you can extract it as explicit struct.

One note — you structs' fields should be exported (Upper Case name), or `json.Unmarshal` (or `json.Marshal`) will fail to process data properly, you could experiment with fields on Play Golang.

http://play.golang.org/p/msu73bwXNb

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
)

const jsonDocument = `
{
    "host": {
        "domain": "localhost",
        "port": 5000
    }
}
`

type Config struct {
  Host struct {
    Domain string
    Port   int
  }
}

func main() {
  cfg := &Config{}
  json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonDocument), cfg)
  fmt.Printf("host: %s:%d\n", cfg.Host.Domain, cfg.Host.Port)
}
```